# Why does wordpress replace my custom child-theme files with old versions of themselves?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

It's like the system is messing with me deliberately. Twice this has happened now:

I make some edit to my own custom child-theme using the theme file editor in the wordpress admin interface, I hit save, and suddenly it has replaced the file with a copy of itself that is the state of a couple weeks ago.

The "last modified" date is the time I hit save but the content is not what I saved.

I'm completely out of ideas why this might happen. I do have backups but this can't keep happening...

EDIT: It might also be that it did the replacing over night and I didn't notice until I hit save (made a tiny adjustment), except the page displayed the correct version until I hit save. I am so confused.

Comment: This might be hard to debug, especially with the lack of actual debugging information in your question.
Perhaps look at what is posted to the server and how it responds in the network tab of your browser developer tools. Check if `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` works and does not return errors.
Also review your .htaccess - e.g. are there any redirects active on `/wp-admin` and/or `/wp-json`? I found WP FSE has issues with forced trailing slashes...

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any information I could give. Especially since I can't reproduce it. It appears to be happening randomly. I figured maybe someone else had this problem as well. I am kinda new to wordpress. But thank you for the input, I now have more to go on than I did and I will look into it.

Comment: is it possible that you installed some security plugin, such as SUCURI https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/ ? I ask because these plugins can be configured to automatically revert edited core / plugins files (to avoid malware infections and stuff like that).

Comment: nothing like that. Elementor+WooCommerce+related. I do have "WP Fastest Cache". Do you think that might serve me an old version of the site? I did try restarting my PC to see if Firefox used an old version of the site on startup (restore tabs) but that wasn't it. Too bad I can't reproduce it on command but I guess I'll try always refreshing the site and checking whether I see the current version whenever I sit down to work and see if it happens again.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your error logs?

Comment: plenty deprecation warnings from the plugins but nothing useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was the problem:

I started my PC, Firefox reloads the last session. I had multiple instances of the page open (different tabs).

I would do work in Tab 1 and in the next session work in Tab 2. Tab 2 would load a cached version of itself from when it was last opened (before the work in Tab 1).

When I did not notice that, I would hit save and the old version would overload the last-saved one.

Oddly, reloading did not help. It would reload the cached version. I had to re-navigate to the page in a new tab.

Hope this will help someone someday.